# Не стандарт / нестандарт

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, названия

Я открываю свой магазин и не знаю как правильно назвать — «не стандарт» или «нестандарт». Не знаю, как пишется слово. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

[нестандарт](https://all_words.academic.ru/48954/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82); -а; *м.; проф.*
1. Нестандартная продукция. **Забраковать нестандарт.**
2. *Лекс., в функции определения.* **Обувь нестандарт.**

Стандарт и нестандарт (по Тихонову: приставка **не-**; корень **-стандарт-**) — это два разных слова.
[Сравните: погода — непогода; правда — неправда; равенство — неравенство.]

Думаю, что для названия магазина подойдет, допустим, **НЕстандарт** — своеобразный, особенный ассортимент; не такое, как у всех, обслуживание.
Примеры есть: радио НЕСТАНДАРТ; НестандАРТ (современное искусство); НеСтандАРТ (рекламно-производственная компания); НестандАрт (мебельный салон)…

[Магазин "Нестандарт"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2782316-kak-pishetsja-nestandart-slitno-ili-razdelno.html) (Большой вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Как назвать - ваш выбор. Как назовете, так и будет правильно. Можете даже придумать новое слово, которого пока нет в языке, - и все равно будет правильно.